# Are there cocktails with wasabi or other spicy ingredients?

Tags: cocktails

Recently I tried a custom cocktail from my barman with wasabi, vodka and some sambuco syrup (not Sambuca, and still no found resource in English to add) and got in love with that cocktail, like my top 5 ever.

Wasabi itself as an ingredient was surprising on mixing with vodka, so I'm trying to find out if there are other coktails with wasabi or other spicy ingredients.

Does anyone know some?

EDIT:If anyone is interested on this Sambuco syrup, can find some info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elderflower_cordial)

Comment: Wow wasabi with vodka, and not with sushi - you are a brave man (or woman) indeed!

Comment: i'm not brave , i just have an excetional barman , who won also lots of challenge...just to say, one time he made me try a cocktail with gin, onion bottled in vinegar and  tomatoes...was REALLY awesome...

Comment: This question is great as it broadens our horizons here and allows us to explore outside our normal thoughts.

Comment: Is the sambuco syrup elderberry or have I got it wrong (again)?  If so then there is a lot of info about it on the internet.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 as long as i'm italian, i know here we have the habit to taking a recipe and change it on how we want, also changing name and so on, here in italy is called Sambuco cause the plant from which it came from is called Sambuco itself.
Still pretty sure that in english the syrup is the one i linked, cause it refers to the same latin name of the Sambuco, and has the same recipe...

Comment: OK, not a problem, I just did a google search as I was interested - the great thing is, all the time we learn something new.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: I've had in bars at least two different cocktails which included ginger. They were great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tabasco or other hot sauces will be a far more common spicy ingredient, and is present in quite a number of cocktails (the [Bloody Mary variants](http://www.eater.com/drinks/2016/2/16/10985162/bloody-mary-cocktail-guide), [Afterburners](http://www.tabascofoodservice.com/foodservice-recipes/recipe/2368/afterburner/)*, [Flatliners](http://www.drinksmixer.com/drink3550.html)). You could even use a vinegar-based hot sauce as the "dirty" part of a dirty martini. [Here](https://www.buzzfeed.com/christinebyrne/deliciously-spicy-cocktails) are more ideas that I haven't tried myself.

Note that unless the wasabi root was grated in front of you, no matter where you are in the world, you almost certainly actually had green-colored horseradish <sup>[1](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/fake-wasabi-horseradish_us_561bd666e4b0082030a33959)</sup>. Horseradish can also be an ingredient in the Bloody Mary family of drinks.

---

*Names for lots of shots are not standardized, so there are a huge number of totally different "Afterburner"s, YMMV.

Comment: the wasaby he used was a sort of past, your link was very good, never thought 'bout it...
Anyway great response, tabasco is a well known , also some fresh pepper could be a good hint

Comment: @anon Yes, and it really depends on what you meant by "spicy"... there are excellent cinnamon-based cocktails too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I like a lot (don't know the exact proportions by hard, sorry):

- Tequila (silver or gold, both work well)
- Agave syrup
- Lime juice
- Red chili pepper
- Fresh coriander leaves
  Shake, strain, add few coriander leaves as garnish

You can let the chili steep in the tequila beforehand, or just shake them along (you'll need a bit more chili then...).